# Why isn't there a named requirement ordered container in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

Many STL containers have both ordered and unordered version, e.g. `map` and `unondered_map`, `set` and `unordered_set`. And on the other hand, some STL algorithms have to be fed in an ordered container to give the correct output. For instance, [std::set_difference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/) will not work correctly on `unordered_set`. So my question is, why isn't there a named requirement that specifies a container is always sorted, such that inputs to algorithms like `set_difference` are constraint to those sorted containers?

Comment: Are you suggesting that functions like `std:set_difference` should not allow iterators from `std::vector` or `std::deque` because it is possible that those containers are not sorted?

Comment: @DrewDormann That would be to hard, but it could realy be beneficial if std::set_difference would refuse to take an unordered_set because that can never work.

Comment: @DrewDormann Maybe a more scrupulous way is to say: we need three named requirements, a) containers whose elements can be arranged by client, b) containers that are guaranteed to be sorted by nature and c) containers that are unordered and there's no way for client to sort it.

Comment: For programmers who are not familiar with underlying implementations,  std:set_difference does not work for `unordered_set` simply makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

> In a way, the STL concept contradicts the original idea of
> object-oriented programming: The STL *separates* data and algorithms
> rather than combining them. However, the reason for doing so is very
> important. In principle, you can combine every kind of container with
> every kind of algorithm, so the result is a very flexible but still
> rather small framework.
> -- from  Nicolai M. Josuttis <<The C++ Standard Library A Tutorial and Reference Second Edition>>

There are three classes of STL containers :

1. sequence containers(array, vector, deque, forward_list, list)
2. associative containers(set, map, multiset, and multimap)
3. unordered associative containers(unordered_set, unordered_map, unordered_multiset, and unordered_multimap)

You can get sorted sequence containers by calling  std::sort for array, vector, deque, sort() member function for forward_list and list.